# How do I structure my findOne() to return the latest entry?

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I have a collection of data stored like this:

```
{
"_id":"62d530c4684721ff4e5325a3",
"clientsNumber":"0705087333",
"dateViewed":"18th July 2022, 1:06:56 PM"
}

{
"_id":"62d530c4684721ff4e5325a3",
"clientsNumber":"0705087444",
"dateViewed":"18th July 2022, 2:36:56 PM"
}

{
"_id":"62d530c4684721ff4e5325a3",
"clientsNumber":"0705087555",
"dateViewed":"18th July 2022, 3:06:56 PM"
}
```

I need `findOne()` to return the latest entry, in this example being:

```
{
"_id":"62d530c4684721ff4e5325a3",
"clientsNumber":"0705087555",
"dateViewed":"18th July 2022, 3:06:56 PM"
}
```

I have tried with the below code but am not getting the desired result:

```
client.db("Billboard_adverts").collection("adverts").findOne({clientsNumber: clientsNumber}).sort({ dateViewed: -1 });
```

How do I structure my `findOne()` query code to return the latest entry based on the dateViewed?

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly for me:

client.db("Billboard_adverts").collection("adverts").findOne({clientsNumber: clientsNumber}).sort( { _id: -1 }).limit(1).toArray();